# Valgrind fails when installing - make

Tags: macos, makefile, valgrind

I've got Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.3, I know that Valgrind may not be compatible with my system. I've successfully ran automake and the svn, however when I try to run **make**, it says:

```
priv/ir_opt.c:5930:14: error: explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'Int' (aka 'int') to itself [-Werror,-Wself-assign]
  for (m = m; m < A_NENV; m++) {
```

Anyone know if this is due to compatibility with Mac OS or something else? Thanks.

Comment: This is not `make`, but the C compiler. Remove the `-Werror` flag wherever it is set (probably in a `Makefile`).

Comment: @Jens Thanks for answering, tried removing all `-Wall` and `-Werror` from Valgrind Makefile, tried removing everything from my ~/.profile as well, however I've noticed that it probably uses Xcode's make, since it printed out `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make`.

Comment: If that didn't help, I suggest to modify the source; since `m = m` is doing nothing, it can safely be removed from ir_opt.c: `for (; m < A_NEW; m++)`.

Comment: Thanks @Jens, worked!

Answer (score 0):

As Jens suggested, I've found `ir_opt.c` (note for people with the same problem: be wary, as there are several `ir_opt.c` files, you need to edit the one in `VEX/priv/ir_opt.c`) and changed the `m = m` to `m = 0`, since the variable `m` was declared as 0 a few lines above.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind won't work on MacOS X Sierra, I have tried for a while.

I understand you got it to install with SVN, so did I, and I never even ran into this error you're having.  But if you actually run `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full -v ./<program>` you will find yourself running into an error.

From what I've read, this is caused by something in the OS X source code that the developers of valgrind aren't able to make modifications to their software for, because the part of OS X causing the error is under license and closed source.  Or it was until recently and they haven't gotten to updating their own source code yet, or something like that.

Anyways, if you want to use valgrind on OS X you'll have to install a virtual machine with linux on it.  I'm using VirtualBox with lubuntu and I'm sharing my home folder to the VM, and I'm not having any problems running memchecks that way.  Any distro should be fine, but IMO the lighter the better.

If for some reason it actually does work for you with valgrind memchecks, then I guess you're just lucky.  I'd still suggest you switch to using a linux VM anyways, because there is no guarantee that valgrind will function fully on OS X and it may not catch everything like it's supposed to.